# How to get text of a selected option from the select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: The HTML and js bellow is a simplified version. Check out the jsfiddle link on the bottom of my post for full demonstration of my problem.

---

I have a select HTML element:

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

I want to get the label of a selected option with jQuery. This, however:

```
alert($("#foo option:selected").text());
```

Returns:

```
a
b
c
```

I want to get just, for example:

```
b
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8KcYY/1/ (click on the "Vybrať značku" button).

Comment: [Seems to work to me](http://jsfiddle.net/tLkRB/). Could you post a non-functional example on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Strange, according to this documentation (http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) it should work.

Comment: Does this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/8KcYY/) not work?

Comment: I have posted it to jsfiddle.

Comment: I modified it slightly, but works the same:  http://jsfiddle.net/qtRhQ/1/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works:

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button" />

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
});
```

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Nyenh/

Even simpler:

```
$('#foo').change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
    alert(selected.val() + ' ' + selected.text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qtRhQ/1/

Comment: I have posted it to jsfiddle.

Comment: Select something in the first select and then click on the button next to it.

Comment: Ok, check out this variation of what you had, which does the same thing:  http://jsfiddle.net/qtRhQ/1/

Comment: You're showing value and text of selected option.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @Kon Not really. What I want is this. When a user clicks on the "Vybrať značku", it will show the text of the selected option element from the select element "Skupina".

Comment: Btw, this is the correct link: http://jsfiddle.net/8KcYY/1/ (first time I posted the wrong one).

Comment: Then just change this:  alert(selected.val() + ' ' + selected.text());
   to this:  alert(selected.text());

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#dropdownlistID").text();
```

This will show all positions in your "dropdownlist". To get only selected item use:

```
 $("#dropdownlistID").val();
```

Or try like

```
 $("#foo").find(":selected").text()
```

instead of

```
$("#foo option:selected").text()
```

Comment: No, that will show the value attribute of the option tag. I want the text that's between option opening and closing tag.